# Can a Double be formatted without scientific notation?

Tags: java, string, double, hibernate-search

I am aware of the various posts floating out there with regards to the same issue.

Mine its a little bit different and it might be a little obvious, but I will need your comments.

I am currently using *Hibernate Search* and *Lucene* to Index entity properties.

I have a bunch of *Double* properties on my entities.

These entities using the default Bridges from *Lucene* (Bridge i.e the one in charge converting *LongToString* and *StringToLong*) are giving me troubles once the scientific notation starts to be used.

I am trying to show on *DataTables* on a .*xhtml* Credit and Debit amounts, their lenght can be as long as 18 digits, and their DataBase (*DB2*) type is *BIGINT*.

1. I can not change the DataBase type
   to Long for example.
2. I can not change either the Double
   type attributes of my entities
   either to for example Long

**So whats the question?**
Is there a way from a String say "1234567890" to retrieve a Double whose format is 1234567890 and not 1.23456789E9 as it is being done by default by `Double.parseDouble(FormattedString)`?

PD: I am aware of the existance of *DecimalFormat*, however take into account using this formater will give me a String formated correctly say : "#######.E0" but what I really need is a Double with such format, however when doing `Double.parseDouble(FormattedString)` I will loose such format.

Hope I was clear and thanks for any help.

Comment: Cast it to long before printing?

Comment: Can't it is being done dynamically on an Iteration over a <p:DataTable>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Is there a way from a String say "1234567890" to retrieve a Double whose value is 1234567890 and not 1.23456789E9 as it is being done by default by `Double.parseDouble(FormattedString)`?**

Your question doesn't really make sense. 1234567890 is the same value as 1.23456789E9 and a double represents one of them, if and only if it also represents the other.

> **I am aware of the existance of DecimalFormat, however take into account using this formater will give me a String formated correctly say : "#######.E0" but what I really need is a Double with such format, however when doing Double.parseDouble(FormatedString) I will loose such format.**

No, there is no way to construct a `Double` so that it is displayed in a certain way. The [`toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28%29) method for `Double` is what it is, and it can't be changed.

The only thing you can do is to for instance use `DecimalFormat` or `String.format` but as you've noted, you'll always end up with a `String`.

Comment: I hope you meant `parseDouble` instead of `toString`? So what you really mean is that `parseDouble` is what it is and can't be changed??

Comment: No, I meant [`toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28%29) (the method that in most circumstances defines how a double is printed).

Comment: Yeah my bad, I thought it was somehow possible to alter the format of a double number but it isnt possible as you are stating. A solution provided by a colleague was to apply the _formatter_ property on the `<h:outputText>` on my .xhtml Additionally I edited the first part of the question to get it clearer. Can you please confirm if a Double type property can not get its format changed?

Comment: You cannot change the default format of `double`, however you can write your own code to produce a `String` from a `double` or a `double` from a `String` any way you wish.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know nothing of Lucene, but you can never have a Double in a .xhtml Document it is always a characterstring. A Double doesn't have a Format, only a String representation of a Double has.

Comment: Well you are right, I forgot to mention how these doubles are being shown. I have a <p:DataTable> iterating over a list of entities who have amongst different properties, the Double type properties I am mentioning here. Therefore disregard the .xhtml part and check my real question **So whats the question** Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got the solution to my problem.
After rounding up what ***aioobe*** and ***Jens Schauder*** said. I am able to format the text dynamically on my .xhtml with the following tag:

```
<h:outputText value="#{recordTable[column.property]}"
              rendered="#{column.header ne 'Details' and
                          column.header eq ('Total Credit Amount' or
                                            'Total Debit Amount')}">
              <f:convertNumber pattern="########"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Thanks for making clear to me these basic stuff I had blurred :)